# Solana spl-token can't create-account on other network

Tags: command-line-interface, solana

I created a token on solana devnet and could easily create a account with create-account command. Then minded the tokens and all went well.

Now I try to go to testnet and create an account for this token but it throws an error:

```
spl-token create-account 8X1oYwCiKbPdcfzQSS3C6DoqZzr319Hv5btnZ6DfMvTi --url=testnet
```

> Creating account 3nYJ1PGggmyjc8Ht2uqCTPeMLkBNGngm7h4THysbPXM6 RPC
> response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing
> Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x2 [18 log messages]

I tried to look up the error in their github but it's not really helping me:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/ea354ab358021aa08f774e2d4028b33ec56d4180/token/program/src/error.rs#L16

#[error("Invalid Mint")]
InvalidMint,

The same problem comes up when I do it the other way around, create token and account on testnet then try to create an account on devnet. (same with mainnet).

I have enough SOL in all the networks so that's not the problem and I have the right authority and keypair.

I feel that im just missing 1 step in the process. Please let me know how to fix this :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create the token on testnet and other networks in order to create ATAs from them

Since you only created the token on devnet, it does not yet exist on testnet

Comment: Thanks Jacob, can you tell me how I create the same token on another network?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You'll have to repeat the step to create the token mint again on testnet, also using the `--url testnet` flag, same as you did on devnet.  Here's the documentation on creating a token mint: https://spl.solana.com/token#example-creating-your-own-fungible-token

Comment: I'm also stuck on this step. Tried creating new token on testnet but getting a different error now of "RPC response error -32602: Invalid param: not a v2.0 Token mint"